# Sql Query to retrieve unique rows with where clause and displaying row count

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have a table with following fields:-

```
device_name,
system_name,
alert_text,
direction,
arrival_time,
ack_time,
ack_status,
Currentval_analog,
Currentval_digital,
Lower_limit,
Upper_limit
```

I want to write a query which retrieves the unique or distinct arrival time and system name where ack_status=0 and direction=came.Arrival time for each system_name should be different.
Along with it,I have to display the number of times the same system_name appears for different arrival_time.

Actually in my database there exist several system_names corresponding to each system_name there is arrival time and sometimes there exist redundancy between system name and arrival time i.e same  arrival_time for the same_system.I want to remove this redundant row and count the total number of same system_name  for different arrival_time corresponding to that system_name along with the where condition fulfilled.

Comment: @radar I don't want to know the arrival_time count but wants to know total number of times the same system_name comes with different arrival_time.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query. I think it will work.

```
;With cte AS
(
    SELECT Arrivaltime, system_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY system_name 
       order BY system_name) 
     AS Rn FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Arrivaltime, system_name FROM YourTableName 
    WHERE ack_status = 0 AND direction = 'came') AS A
)

SELECT A.Arrivaltime, A.system_name, (SELECT MAX(Rn) FROM Cte AS B 
WHERE A.system_name = B.system_name) 
AS Count FROM Cte AS A

SELECT arrival_time, system_name
FROM YourTableName WHERE ack_status = 0 AND direction = 'came'
GROUP BY arrival_time, system_name
```

Comment: I want the count total number of times the same system_name comes with different arrival_time with the where clause and error is shown on DESC

Comment: how on the same system_name different count values are shown??I want to count the number of times a system_name appears for all values of arrival_time.Arrival time should be distinct.

Comment: I again changed the data. Recheck back. If it fails. The only way to get the correct answer is by providing enough details about table content, expected result with sample data.

Comment: no system_name is coming with i run the above query and i have edited my question for better clearance.Thanks for all the efforts.

Comment: Wen you want sysname add it to the query. check it

Comment: oks.Can you give a sql query which give the first and last arrival time for a system_name??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT arrival_time, system_name, COUNT(system_name) AS SystemCount 
FROM YourTableName WHERE ack_status = 0 AND direction = 'came'
GROUP BY arrival_time, system_name
```

Comment: how on the same system_name different count values are shown??I want to count the number of times a system_name appears for all values of arrival_time.Arrival time should be distinct.

Comment: this count suggest that for arrival_time the system_name repeated=corresponding count.

Comment: if you want you can remove the system_name in select if you are confused.

Comment: I want to count the system_name for different values of arrival time.Actually in my database,there are systems which have same arrival time,I want to remove repeating arrival_time for the same system and count the total number of same system_name which appears for different arrival time